# Phonegap download file and save in internal storage

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to download file from server and then save it to the internal storage of the device using phonegap. Here is what i have so far

```
if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("test.mp3", {
      create: true,
      exclusive: false
    }, function(fileEntry){
      var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath; // equals /test.mp3
      // sPath = "file:///storage/sdcard0/test.mp3";
      var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      fileEntry.remove();
      fileTransfer.download(
        ringtone.streamUrl,
        sPath,
        function(theFile){
          alert(theFile);
        }
        );
    });
  }, null);
}
```

The problem is that when i give the absolute file path to download like `file:///storage/sdcard0/test.mp3` it downloads the file perfectly to the internal storage but does not work if use the sPath variable. From what i understand is that i am not able to get the absolute path the internal storage directory. How do we get the internal storage path in the `file:///` format in android using phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the standard or recommended way of doing this but i have tested this on LG G2, Samasung Galaxy S3 and on 2 Motorolla Phones and it works perfectly. 
I simply connected to the emulator using the below command

```
adb shell
```

and entered

```
ls -la
```

In the result there was a directory named sdcard in the root `/` directory that was a symlink to the original sdcard folder that is located somewhere else

```
ls -la

sdcard -> storage/sdcard0
```

So the path `file:///sdcard/test.mp3` did the trick for me.

Comment: I want to do save image in internal memory if no sd card . My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255938/file-download-to-show-in-download-list-ionic